# ASP.NET Core Web API : cannot hit any end points

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

I'm using .NET 6.0 and can't get any controller methods to be execute.  I went back and created the simplest controller I could think of and it also doesn't work. Swagger picks up all controller and method I have created including the more complex ones. But when I executed any of them I get a 404 error. If I paste the url into a browser directly I get the same error. However, the service is running.

I've spent 3 days trying to figure out why. But have made no progress.

Here is my simple controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CoreWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class testController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            // Replace this with the string you want to return
            string responseString = "Hello, World!";

            // Return the string as an OK response
            return Ok(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my program class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using CoreWebAPI;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using CoreWebAPI.Data.DBContexts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CoreWebAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

And this is my `Startup` class:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CoreWebAPI.Data.DBContexts;
using CoreWebAPI.Mapings;
using AutoMapper;

namespace CoreWebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configure services here
            services.AddDbContext<BuzzAlertDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HomeConnection")!)); ;

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMappingProfile));

            // add swagger
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                // Define your Swagger documentation version and title
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CoreWebAPI", Version = "v1" });

                // Enable XML comments (if you have XML documentation)
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                //c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // Other app configurations

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                // Enable Swagger UI only in development mode
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CoreWebAPI");
                    c.EnableValidator(null);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // Other app configurations
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I have missed something fundamental in my project setup.  But can't see it.

Any help appreciated.

Erick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating default web app and compare startup code: you will see some differences.

Main difference is wrong builder used, you should use `WebApplicationBuilder` which enables you to further configure your app to work correctly.

I also don't see call to `services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();`

So, below I attach corrected Program.cs file that now will run correctly (I moved methods `Startup` - you can compare their implementations:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        var app = builder.Build();

        Configure(app, builder.Environment);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }


    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Configure services here
        //services.AddDbContext<BuzzAlertDBContext>(options =>
        //    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HomeConnection")!)); ;

        services.AddControllers();

        //services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        //services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMappingProfile));

        // add swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            // Define your Swagger documentation version and title
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CoreWebAPI", Version = "v1" });

            // Enable XML comments (if you have XML documentation)
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            //c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }

    public static void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Other app configurations

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            // Enable Swagger UI only in development mode
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CoreWebAPI");
                c.EnableValidator(null);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Other app configurations
    }
}
```

Then adding `TestController` to `Controllers` project directory works correctly:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I used your code and made a few tweaks, and my controller works.  The rest of my controllers use DI and still error out by I suspect the issue is with some kind of configuration setting as well.  Will see if i can work it out or may have to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is under "Other app configurations", you're missing a call such as app.MapControllers() that adds the routing for controllers to your middleware pipeline.